# Duplicate Content Issue - Local SEO

Tags: duplicate-content, local-seo

I have a website where we created a unique and informational content and now we want to target same content City wise. So I don't have much to change as just changed the city name for other pages.

So will google count it a duplicate content?

As it's mine content so should not be the case.

And also it's highly relevant on the page so won't impact the page experience and information is highly relevant on the page? Will google count this as a good practice?

Do I need to make any SEO changes here?

Answer (score 2):

Just changing every occurrence of a single word won't help you.

Google won't penalise you for duplicate content, providing that content was first spidered on your website. But Google will merely consider it canonically identical to another page if it's insufficiently different, regardless of whether you use rel="canonical" tags.

That means your "new" pages won't be indexed and won't provide you with any benefit.

Comment: I have multiple pages so cannot make canonical tag to parent one. I have seen pages getting indexed for other website from where I got this idea.
However I think google shouldn't have issue as content is mine and also add value to the end user also.

Comment: @JaswantSingh If you want the page to rank for a new keyword, then a canonical link isn't what you want anyway. Other sites may have made other changes to the pages or Google's index changes may have not taken affect yet, which is why you're seeing those results.

Comment: This problem is with so many clients and I think after doing research I got the answer.